# Why won't Farkas give me any work to do and is it related to this possible Purity quest bug?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

First, after the Companions questline, I married Farkas. However, now he won't give me any work even though I paid all my fines and moved in with him. I also tried to cure Villas, but he doesn't even come with me to the flame to cure him. In my journal, the [Purity](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Purity) quest is marked as finished even though I haven't done a thing.

Comment: I've seen you completed the quest line, so why are you expecting jobs from him if you completed everything?

Answer (score 2):

If you can, trying loading a save before that. If he follows you then go to Ysgramor's tomb and activate the fire. His wollf spirit might come, and then kill it.